# Set repeat alarm for every year in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am building an alarm application in android.Till now i am able to create repeat alarm for every day,week and every month.

Now my requirement is to set repeat alarm for every year.
TIA

Comment: can you show us the code you are using for setting it by day/week/month? shouldnt be any different for year.

Comment: To set it repeat every year.

e.g. if i set alarm for 19-1-2018,then next alarm should fire automatically on 19-1-2019,19-1-2020 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set alarm after every year, each time alarm is fired you can start a new service intent which will be set alarm for next consecutive year.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 0, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: will the alarm service be active after 1 year on phone ? Is there an actual test here that proves that AlarmManager will still fire an alarm after a very long period of time?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to repeat alarm every year. Use [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/format/DateUtils) this will ease your work if you are working on Alarm App.

```
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alrarmTime, DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is answer https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

I think you can set alarm for next year, when time come alarmIntent run and set alarm for year + 1 , this can make it repeat every year

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately next year
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);

alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 0, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: this to set repeating alarm at 14:00 for everyday i am asking to set it repeat every year.

e.g. if i set alarm for 19-1-2018,then next alarm should fire automatically on 19-1-2019,19-1-2020 and so on...

Comment: I think you can do like set alarm for next year, when alarmIntent call for start service, this service will set alarm again for year + 1. I will add more example in answer